# Multiple figures with different caption set up commands

Tags: floats, captions, sv-classes

So I'm trying to place in margin figures, as well as central figures. And for the margin figures, I want to make something like this:
[image]

But for the center figures, I want the caption label to be like the one below, in which the number is from the chapter and the figure number is renewed to 1. 
[image]

For each, I've tried creating it, but it only becomes one or the other. If I try both then it gives me a preamble error. What am I doing wrong? Please let me know. MWE below:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs,12pt]{svmono}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,sf,font=small,figurewithin=chapter]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,skip=1pt,font={bf,sf}}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction to Chemistry Laboratory}
\marginpar{  
    \centering     
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm]{Beaker.png}  
     \captionof{figure}{Beaker}
    } 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,2}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.2)node[below,scale=0.4]{\x};
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,1.9}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.075);
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,1.5}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.15);
            };
\draw (0,0)--(2,0);
\draw[fill=lightgray] (0,0.05) rectangle (1.625,0.45);
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period,labelformat={simple}}
\caption{This}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use a captionof command for the marginfigure. Simply use some bold text.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks! That did the trick. But, it doesn't print the 1.1. It only prints 1. How can i fix this?

Comment: Remove the counterwithout command if you want your figures to be numbered with the chapter number.

Comment: @leandriis Omg yay. That really did the trick. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What will your document be used for?

Comment: @leandriis It is just transferring a word document lab manual into a Latex version.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize my above comments into an answer:

To add a text to the images in the margin, simply type some text there without the use of `\captionof`. If you want to apply a uniform style to all thouse texts, you can define your own command as I did in the following MWE.

To number the other figures with chapter number.figure number, just remove `\counterwithout{chapter}{figure}` and `\usepackage{chngcntr}`. The `svmono` class default is numbering figures, tables and equations per chapter.

In the following MWE, I have also removed anything related to the `caption` package. Since the documentclass you use was supplied by a publisher, you might have to stick with their design choices if you want to publish with them.

I have also removed the `graybox` since this is not a valid class option and will throw a corresponding warning.

Lastly, I would recommend to either specify the width OR the height of a image in order to avoid distorting the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[envcountchap,sectrefs,12pt]{svmono}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[labelfont=bf,sf,font=small,figurewithin=chapter]{caption}
%\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,skip=1pt,font={bf,sf}}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Remove demo option in actual document.
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\unnumberedcaption}[1]{\bfseries \sffamily #1}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction to Chemistry Laboratory}
\marginpar{  
    \centering     
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2.75cm]{Beaker.png}  
    \unnumberedcaption{Beaker}
    } 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,2}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.2)node[below,scale=0.4]{\x};
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,...,1.9}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.075);
            }
            \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,1.5}{
            \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.15);
            };
\draw (0,0)--(2,0);
\draw[fill=lightgray] (0,0.05) rectangle (1.625,0.45);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\captionsetup{labelsep=period,labelformat={simple}}
\caption{This}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```